# Two level nested mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I want to be able to create the following structure in mongoose

```
{
    "clientId": 9,
    "uniqueNodeId": "REFRESH:NODE:123123123_9_231",
    "parent": null,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "templates": [
        {
            "name": "temp",
            "body": "temp",
            "url": "temp",
            "imageUrl": "temp",
            "title": "temp",
            "personaId": 123,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "uniqueTemplateId": "REFRESH:TEMPLATE:123123123_9_231"
        }
    ]
}
```

templates is an array and of json objects.What is the right way to do this?
I tried doing the below code.

```
var folderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "clientId": {type: Number, required: true},
    "uniqueNodeId": {type: String, required: true},
    "parent": {type: String, required: true},
    "status": {type: String, required: true},
    "templates": [{
        "name": {type: String, required: true},
        "body": {type: String, required: true},
        "url": {type: String, required: true},
        "imageUrl": {type: String, required: true},
        "title": {type: String, required: true},
        "personaId": {type: String, required: true},
        "status": {type: String, required: true},
        "uniqueTemplateId": {type: String, required: true}
    }]
});
```

However i am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Undefined type at `paths.clientId`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
```

What does this mean and how to correct it?

Comment: if you have included  Number = Schema.Types.Number in your file remove it,because it has to reffer built-in JavaScript Number

Comment: i havent added anything like that

Answer (score 0):

A nicer way you define this is separate the Schema definitions:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var templateSchema = new Schema({
    "name": {type: String, required: true},
    "body": {type: String, required: true},
    "url": {type: String, required: true},
    "imageUrl": {type: String, required: true},
    "title": {type: String, required: true},
    "personaId": {type: String, required: true},
    "status": {type: String, required: true},
    "uniqueTemplateId": {type: String, required: true}
},{ _id: false});


var folderSchema = new Schema({
    "clientId": {type: Number, required: true},
    "uniqueNodeId": {type: String, required: true},
    "parent": {type: String},
    "status": {type: String, required: true},
    "templates": [ templateSchema ]
});

var Folder = mongoose.model( "Folder", folderSchema );
```

The `_id: false` part is optional, and a way of telling mongoose to not automatically generate an `_id` field on the entries inside the array. That is the default, so it is up to you whether you want this or not.

This also makes for a clean separation in case you change you mind and want to have a referenced model rather than an embedded schema. It is also worthwhile in case you want to re-use components somewhere else.

So on minimal usage:

```
Folder.findOne({},function(err,doc) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log(doc);

});
```

With a collection with your data in place named `folders` as per standard Mongoose naming

Produces:

```
{ _id: 5368c2267ea39d89989df13c,
  clientId: 9,
  uniqueNodeId: 'REFRESH:NODE:123123123_9_231',
  parent: null,
  status: 'ACTIVE',
  templates:
   [ { name: 'temp',
       body: 'temp',
       url: 'temp',
       imageUrl: 'temp',
       title: 'temp',
       personaId: '123',
       status: 'ACTIVE',
       uniqueTemplateId: 'REFRESH:TEMPLATE:123123123_9_231' } ] }
```

Comment: Tried this as well. Gives the same error as mentioned in the question

Comment: @nnm Can't say that I can reproduce the same. The above causes no errors for me. Note the model definition part. Make sure you are doing things the same. BTW your data exhibits a `null` value on a field you have marked as a required `String` type, so change that or get a future error.

Comment: i have edited The error that it gives.Can you take a look now?

Comment: what do you mean by this "With a collection with your data in place named folders as per standard Mongoose naming". I have invoked the schema with the following line of code var folderModel = mongoose.model("refresh_hierarchy", folderDbObject.folderSchema); with folderDbobject being the modules variable.

Comment: Mongoose pluralizes the name of the collection by default. If you want to override this and use a specific collection name there is a third argument to the constructor. See the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model) for this.